# what's the right way to write the mobile page?

Tags: jquery-mobile, meta

A week ago, I get a task to develop a site on mobile. After searching the engine, I choose jQuery Mobile! All things like more simple. Until now, I found something was wrong.
Maybe I lost myself, between `responsive html` and `mobile page`.
To test my page, I use two tools. One is the chrome developer, and other is the Opera Mobile Emulator!

As the e.g, I write a page with jQuery Mobile.To me, the first question is to change the `border-radius` size. My page link another css. But the CSS didn't work well, they can't make the right size. After some test, I have to change the file named `jquery.mobile.css`, to make it the size which I need.
[image: the button radius]

After that, All things test under chrome is look ok,but the bad things happend.The page can't work well under the test tool Opera-mobile-Emulator!

After that, I added the code

`<meta id="viewport" name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0">`

to my page.Some thing began to look right.

The mobile page to me feel hard. What's the right way to develop them, with jQuery Mobile and how to test them quickly? Help me, the mobile page deeply hurt me. Is there something wrong to my method???

Comment: jQuery Mobile is responsive to any screen size. It works on mobile phones as well as on desktop. adding `meta` tag is essential http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/#Viewportmetatag you can use your own CSS theme (themeroller) or do some overriding.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything particularly wrong with your method or approach.  The mobile stuff can be tricky and frustrating.

The big problem is dealing with multiple devices and trying to make it work right on all of them.

The trick I've found is to have 'slightly' different css for some devices.  You don't need to change all the css just bits.

I have used this in the past, http://www.jquery4u.com/mobile/detect-mobile-devices-jquery/, and it seems to work pretty well.

There is also another tool called hammerjs, http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/, which allows you to have swipe events on elements which i also use.

But ultimately, mobile development can be very frustrating and fiddly.